# WARNING:absl:Found untraced functions such as _jit_compiled_convolution_op while saving in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

i just trained a cnn with 99% accuracy on the mnist dataset. my model is working fine and giving accurate results. but when i converted my `h5` model to a `tflite` model, im getting only one result at every time. ie :
[image]
[image]

code to convert my `h5` model into a `tflite` model :

```
tf_lite_interpreter=tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
with open("mnist_tflite.tflite","wb") as f:
  f.write(tf_lite_interpreter.convert())
```

i noticed that i get this warning when converting

```
WARNING:absl:Found untraced functions such as _jit_compiled_convolution_op while saving (showing 1 of 1). These functions will not be directly callable after loading.
```

also, when i removed `Conv2D` and `MaxPooling2D` layers, the warning was gone

model's structure :

```
model=tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),input_shape=(28,28,1),activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation=tf.nn.softmax),
])
```

why is this happening?

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hi @0xN1nja, kindly share complete code so that we can replicate it and assist you better. Thank you!

Comment: @Tfer3 are you on discord?

Comment: At the moment we are active on Tensorflow Forum, GitHub and StackOverflow and not available on Discord. Thank you!